# Page (router view) dependant header style in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

## A little background...

This may seem like a basic issue, or something that could be easily solved with `$emit`, however, I think events may be a bit overkill for what I am trying to achieve, and as such, would like to see if anyone has an alternative, either by design, or by something I am not aware of in Vue...

Consider the following structure:

**App.vue**

```
<template>

    <div id="app">

        <!-- Include the main site header -->
        <main-header></main-header>

        <!-- Include the content of the current page -->
        <router-view></router-view>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

    import Header from 'core-js/components/core/Header';

    export default {

        components: {
            'main-header': Header
        }

    }

</script>
```

**SomePage.vue** - *router view content*

```
<template>

    <main id="main-content" role="main">

        <!-- All the page content here... -->

    </main>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        // Set the component properties here...

    }

</script>
```

## What am I actually trying to achieve!?

Notice that the `main-header` component is a sibling to the `router-view` component... Very simply, I would like to add a `class` to the `main-header` component based on the content of the `router-view`.

For example, let's say that `SomePage.vue` has dark content, we will want to add the `light` class to the `main-header` component.

I appreciate this could be fixed in a matter of seconds with `$emit`, but I am hesitant to use events on something so basic.

In short, can anyone suggest an alternative solution to Vue events, or a better design structure?

## Additional Information

Just to make it clear what I am trying to achieve, see the following `App.vue` template:

```
<template>

    <div id="app">

        <!-- Include the main site header -->
        <main-header :class="{ light: lightHeader }"></main-header>

        <!-- Include the content of the current page -->
        <router-view></router-view>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

    import Header from 'core-js/components/core/Header';

    export default {

        components: {
            'main-header': Header
        },

        data() {
            return {
                lightHeader: false
            }
        }

    }

</script>
```

Then, `SomePage.vue` would somehow set `lightHeader` to true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider adding a meta field to each route in `router.ts`, like so:

```
routes: [{
    name: 'header',
    component: Header,
    meta: {
        headerClass: 'light'
   }
}]
```

Then you would use it in your template like:

```
<template>    
    <div id="app">    
        <main-header :class="$route.meta.headerClass"></main-header>
        <router-view></router-view>    
    </div>    
</template>
```

See the example I made here: https://jsfiddle.net/wugq6typ/

Comment: Ah, this rings a bell... I think I did this before a while ago! Thank you! This is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for!

Comment: @BenCarey No problem, happy to help!